# code first membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, code-first, entity-framework-5, membership-provider, simplemembership

How can I integrate EF 5.0 with membership provider using code first?

I have my own database schema which I want to use for registration of users etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

It is very easy to use it together with EF.

**Update**

For MVC4 I would start with the blank template.

you need `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` to set up the database.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "Id", "UserName", true);
```

It takes as parameters a name of a connectionstring, the table, a unique identifier column and the username-column.

The model I use for this piece of code above is:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

To log someone in:

```
 WebSecurity.Login(aUsername, aPassword);
```

The method above returns a bool, if it is true, login was successfull.

In the Web.config you **do not** need to define a membershipProvider as it was with default ASP.NET Membership.

If you need to gain access to the provider (to delete an account):

```
var provider = (SimpleMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider;
provider.DeleteAccount(aUsername); // Delete the account
provider.DeleteUser(aUsername, true); // delete the user and its data
```

For creating a new user (with my given model in this case)

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(aUsername, aPassword, new { Email = aEmail, FirstName = aFirstName, LastName = aLastName });
```

Benefit is, that you can now use your model for other EF classes as a foreign key without having the hassle when you want to do this with the normal asp.net membership. :-)

Comment: Hi, if you use the mvc 4 internet application template. What would you modify to make it use your database schema / EF model?

Comment: +1 good point,   Create a new project of type MVC4 internet app. It is a good place to start for "settings" in web.config.

Comment: I updated my answer. Personally I would go with a blank template, because most of the time I delete much from the default internet template, because I dont need it or I need to move it to other classes / namespaces so I can faster to it by myself :)

Comment: Hi, your user table, is that auto generated code or did you created that yourself? I accidently commented this to soadyp instead of you.

Comment: I did create this by myself

Comment: This is the advantage when using the simple membership provider: You do it as you want to have it. No auto generated tables, no stored procedures. Just you and your POCOs :-)

Comment: Do you use migrations to save it all in the database?

Comment: Yes, you can use migrations as well if you have to change your model. There should not be a problem.

Comment: I'm still wondering how you save it to the database if you don't have an edmx template.

Comment: Just as a usual code first approach http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e

This is actually nothing to do with EF.

EF is just a way to read data.

See also FORMS Authentication 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Hi, I need to write data as well, does that change things?

Comment: No, you need to investigate Simpla memberships / custom membership implementation docu

Comment: Hi, your user table, is that auto generated code or did you created that yourself?