# Azure Membership details - how to store user/login details for multiple applications in one MS SQL database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database, membership-provider, simplemembership

I'm trying to design MVC4.5 website on Azure with latest EF but stuck in setting up membership and role base authentication.

I'm somewhat lost in MembershipProvider, SimpleMembershipProvider and ExtendedMembershipProvider.

I found that unlike SqlMembershipProvider the SimplememberShipProvider is not designed to store multiple applications (through ApplicationName and ApplicationID) in a single database and map users accordingly so that business can run multiple applications with only one database.

I hear all praises of SimpleMembershipProvider, my question is how should the database/providers be designed so that I'm able to store user's in association with respective applications in a single database. User registration info must be completely independent from same user name in other application. I also need new features of Open Authentication.

Broadly, my queries are:

1. Is it possible to use SimpleMmebershipProvider to differentiate between multiple applications in a single database.
2. I'm thinking to modify existing schema structure made by SimpleMembershipProvider to include ApplicationId column , but then how would even a custom provider that is inherited from Extended membership provider add ApplicationId against any user.
3. Is there any other provider available or any article that would guide in implementing custom membership provider with custom database design along with features of open authentication.

   Or am I going with completely wrong approach?

Answering to the queries of [BernardG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876653/bernardg)

1. Do you want a "head" url/site, then redirect users to the proper
       application, or

   > No, sites should not appear related nor will be redirect to other.
2. Do you want a user to enter into any application and
       then be redirected to another one he is registered in.

   > Again no, each application should have it's own registration process. Further two applications can have same username but these accounts would not be related.
3. Can a user register into any application?

   > Yes.
4. If not, how do you limit that?

   > Not limiting.
5. What do you mean by this?"User registration info must be completely
       independent from same user name in other application."

   > Refering to answer to point 2, if there are 4 applications with one database and a user registers for one application, he must need to register again to have access to other application. Hence for any user the sites must not appear related.
6. Do you want to duplicate users info into each applications?

   > As per my understanding of the question a combination of username and email address (considering this combination makes any user account unique) can again be stored against another application even with different profile information.

Actually I'm used to the classic membership approach used in ASP.net 2.0 and I'm missing the application Id column for separation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14713393/219615 states that columns can be added to existing tables, if yes then is it a good design to access auto generated with added columns through EF or through a modified provider?

Answer (score 1):

If I may, I believe your question has a lot more to do with design and establishing clearly the features you want, rather than a specific membership provider, knowing that you can do about anything you want with SimpleMembership.

My questions, and I believe those are the questions you have to ask yourself before going further, are:

1. Do you want a "head" url/site, then redirect users to the proper
       application, or
2. Do you want a user to enter into any application and
       then be redirected to another one he is registered in.
3. Can a user register into any application?
4. If not, how do you limit that?
5. What do you mean by this?"User registration info must be completely
       independent from same user name in other application."
6. Do you want to duplicate users info into each applications?

It looks to me that this is all about database(s) design, and analysis, for your real needs. Once that's properly done, the part about membership tables will be easily solved.

Comment: Please see updated question; couldn't answer in comment section.

Comment: OK, I just read your update. if I understand, these applications are separated, right? Do you "need" to have a single database? Why not have as many DB as applications?

You can certainly add as many tables/columns/rows you want to the Simple Membership schema. I believe you should have as many schemas in your DB as applications, and a UserID link to the schemas.